Does Apache cache virtual host files
I have a subdomain virtual host
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@mydomain.com
    ServerName demo.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/demo
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

previously i had DocumentRoot set to /var/www/html/dev/store but now it has been changed to /var/www/html/dev/demo. Even though i have deleted the directory  /var/www/html/dev/store the old content is being downloaded when i am accessing www.demo.mydomain.com.
I have restared apache2, accessing website in incognito mode but still i am getting old content from deleted directory.
Please help me if virtual host cache the demo.mydomain.com.conf file ?
